# Word similar to nepotism/favouritism toward another culture or religion

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, religion

Hi I'm trying to find a word to describe a situation as follows:

Giving better care to a patient of a particular religion or culture because they asked for it specifically.
Not the same religion as the caregiver, therefore I don't think it's nepotism.
I'm trying to write a paper asking why we do not give this 'better' care to all of our patients, not just those that ask for it.

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `bias` ? Although not specific to religion, it does reflect the situation.

Comment: chauvinism - excessive support for one's own group ... etc.  -- http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/chauvinism

Comment: 'Discrimination' can be positive as well as negative.

Comment: I don't understand. When faced with two individuals with the same condition, and both ask for a level a care, the institution will grant to one and deny the other based on what? Does the institution make a background check before making a decision?

Comment: jxh the specific cases involve care of premature babies. A Jehovah's Witness family will receive specific treatments to reduce likelihood of transfusion. The same care could be given to non Jehovah's Witness families, however it is not. Transfusion is high in risk. Therefore the first family are receiving better/safer care because of their religious belief.

Comment: *..., however it is not*, even if asked? Or, is it just that the treatment would be considered optional, and thus not covered by insurance?

Comment: In the UK we don't have insurance, everything is given as standard.  However if you make enough noise about something out of the ordinary, it will be given to you.

Answer (score 1):

[**Favouritism** (favoritism)](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/favouritism)

noun:

the practice of giving special treatment to a person or group

Comment: This has been downvoted; I'm not going to grumble because I realise that the important feature may be the '*asking for* special treatment' element; something that 'favouritism' doesn't necessarily reflect.  I'll leave the answer here though, for reference.

Comment: (and of course, the fact that it appears in the question. Doh.)

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of one particular word that meets the definition you've suggested. However, there are a number of words (often compounds) that express thoughts about a specific culture or religion. In many cases, these words combine an ethnic, national, or religious term with a compound such as anti-, -philia, or -phobia.

1. Germanophobia: strong dislike of, or prejudice against, Germans.
2. Italiophilia: love of or favoritism towards Italy, Italians, and Italian culture.
3. Antisemitism: hatred of Jews, Judaism, and Jewish culture.
4. Papist: a derogatory euphemism (of Protestant origin) for a Roman Catholic.
5. Anglocentrism: a tendency to regard English culture, society, or language as pre-eminent.
6. Japanophile: One who loves Japanese culture, history, language, etc.
7. Semitophilia/Judeophilia: the opposite of antisemitism.
8. Anti-Protestantism: disdain for Protestantism.

Note that the first six words exist in the OED, whereas the remainder do not.

Answer (score 0):

Your description seems to imply that the crux of the issue is that the care is better *once requested*, rather than any religion based bias. If my understanding is correct, you could suggest excellent care be give **by default** rather than **upon request**.

If a single word is needed, [bias](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bias?s=t) or [partisanship](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/partisanship) might fit the bill.